# Applescript iTunes: can't find the loupe (Magnifying glass) in the Search box

Tags: applescript, itunes

I am trying to write a script to set the "loupe" on the Search box in iTunes.

This works:

```
confirm text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
```

This doesn't:

```
confirm menu button 1 of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
```

I get the dreaded "System Events got an error: Cant get menu button 1 of text field 1 of window iTunes Invalid index".

So far I have "confirmed" these:

```
confirm text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm text field 0 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm menu button of text field 0 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm menu button of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm button of text field 0 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm button of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm text field of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm menu button of text field of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm button of text field of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
confirm text field of text field of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes"
```

Comment: I'm surprised the 1st snippet worked for you - didn't for me in iTunes 11.2.2. I can confirm that iTunes applies trickery: the text field that appears in the object hierarchy is NOT the one whose children are the magnifying icon and the clear-search-text button. While you can _discover_ the true parent text field by carefully mousing to the very top edge of the _visible_ text box in Accessibility Inspector (watch for element `AXChildren` to show 2 child elements in the `Attributes` pane), you apparently cannot _access it programmatically_ (at least in AppleScript, as far as I can tell).

Comment: Interesting! thanks for pointing this out... so far I got these two working


display dialog description of text field 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes" as string

display dialog description of text field 0 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes" as string

And yes, they both contain the same string, first "Search Library", and then, when you switch the loupe to "Song" (for example) they both show the string "Song".

But I can't find what is below these, not yet.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance with the tools of this site, I am new

Comment: Wow!, I am blown away, a lot of elements appear to be confirmed but I can't quite point out which one has the button

Comment: Neither `text field 0` nor `text field 1` have any child UI elements (`UI elements of text field 0`, e.g.), sadly, and judging by their properties they may even refer to the same field. I still don't know how to programmatically get at the _true_ text field I described in my first comment.

Comment: Do you know how to dump the contents of one of the nodes as strings (the class hierarchy). Is it possible? Thanks man!

Comment: Just do `return properties of ...` and examine the result in AppleScript Editor (btw, if you want to highlight code in _comments_ here, enclose the snippets in backticks).